Не появляются кнопки в тг боте
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn1 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup('Тест')
    markup.row(btn1)
    btn2 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup('Тест1')
    btn3 = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup('Тест3')
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет', reply_markup=markup)


А вопрос то какой?

Проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь добавить не объект кнопок, а markup.
Вы указали в каждой переменной кнопок ReplyKeyboardMarkup, вместо KeyboardButton.
Вот исправленный вариант:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)

    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton(text='Тест')
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton(text='Тест1')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton(text='Тест3')

    markup.row(btn1)
    markup.row(btn2, btn3)

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Привет', reply_markup=markup)

bot.infinity_polling(skip_pending=True)

